# How to implement stateless management for oauth /authorize token flow

Tags: node.js, oauth

I'm using Node.js for the implementation of an api, but the answer is could probably be answered in a language agnostic way.

Given an authorize flow url that looks like this:

```
https://auth.example.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=callback_url&response_type=response_type&state=nonce
```

I'd like to execute this flow via an api.

- User is redirected from an app (e.g. native mobile or web spa) to an
  api endpoint `/{third_party_oauth_privder}/token` (this api is built
  by me)
- The redirect from step one comes along with a bearer token for
  accessing the api I'm building (providing, amongst other things, identity of the user).
- I need to redirect the user via an authorization url similar to the
  one above, and once the user presses "allow" after authenticating with the third part oauth provider, the user will be redirected back to an endpoint in the api I'm building. At this point, I need to be able to associate the authorization context (token and allowed 3rd part user data) with the user in my system. **I would like to do this in a stateless manner from the api perspective.**

Libraries like passport seem to do this with session state, but I don't want a session in the api (even just for this one use case). I could leverage the nonce by writing it along side the user profile information in my system, and looking up the nonce from the state param on the callback to find the associated user without maintaining any state in the api... but that seems odd.

What is an oauth compliant way to deal with this scenario? Do I really have to maintain a session state for just this flow to make this work? If so, how would this scale? Would I need to store that session state in Redis to ensure the callback api instance would have this session state? There's got to be a reasonably elegant solution that doesn't require state :/ or maybe not.

Any suggestions / examples / links / etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This answer may help your decision-making: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/346868

Comment: @vm909 - I would buy into that more if I was dealing with a web application, but it's an api. Implementing session state with distributed cache to back this session state seems... a bit crazy, but maybe it just has to be done that way :shrugs: ... either way, thanks for the link.

Comment: Oh, totally. I should have worded my comment better; I didn't mean to imply that the link would have the answer to your exact question. But there's lots of good discussion there that seemed relevant to what you're asking.

Comment: @vm909 - The more and more I'm looking into it, the more is seems like you just have to manage a flow such as the one I'm describing with state :(